# ng-click not working when adding 'disabled' class in materializecss

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I'm using AngularJS and MaterializeCSS framework in my project and for buttons it has a 'disabled' class to show them greyed out.

In angular adding or removing a class does not affect the functionality of ng-click.
We have to manually add logic in callback of ng-click to prevent any disabled buttons from working.

But this is a new scenario I'm facing where just adding a 'disabled' class to the button stops the working of ng-click.

I'm adding the 'disabled' class via ng-class

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" ng-class="{'disabled' : vm.disabled}" 
ng-click="vm.counter=vm.counter+1">Counter++</button>
<span>Times Clicked: {{vm.counter}}</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="test5" ng-model="vm.disabled" />
```

Here is plunker for demo.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZP7CIkEW1lLFjHx3xTGV?p=preview

**Guys, I'm not looking for a solution or some fix about how to make it work. I'm looking for an explanation. Why is it happening?**
**Thanks :)**

Comment: use the `ng-disabled` directive?

Comment: or `ng-click="boolean && myFunction()"`

Comment: actually my question is how and why is ng-click not working only by adding a 'disabled' class. I don't want to know how to make it work..

Comment: You should ask materializecss author i think. That is the css library do.

Comment: Because your logic may imply that the button works if it has that class.

Comment: Otherwise, it may restrict the programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because materializecss has `.btn.disabled {pointer-events: none;}`

To make it work, add:

```
.btn.disabled {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```